# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on other server does not decode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have german "Umlaute" in my database, saved as HTML entities -> ü => "#252;".

On my local server (IIS on Windows 7) decoding with HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() works perfectly but when I publish my application to my real webserver (IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2) the strings are not decoded and I see the HTML Entities.

Is there a configuration option?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe would be an egregious bug in `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` which is extremely unlikely. For debugging purposes, add to your page:

```
<%: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#252;") %>
```

And you'll see that it works fine. The bug that your application has is somewhere else. Can't tell where with the given information. Probably, you just pass in unexpected data.

> Is there a configuration option?

There is no setting "DisableHtmlDecodeBugs" if that's what you mean...

---

And on 2nd look I see that your entity syntax is just wrong. `#252;` should be `&#252;`. As I said, assume that `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` has no bugs.

Comment: I tried it directly on the page and it works. By configuration option I meant something for IIS, Windows, Language because it works on one machine and not on the other with exactly the same code etc.... but the "DisableAllBugs" Options sounds good...

Comment: When you hard-code it, does it still not work on the problematic server?! That is so unlikely that I'd rather think you misinterpret some output or are not looking at the right output/server.

Comment: No, when I hard-code it, it works as it should. For now I've disabled the .HtmlEncode part in my app. Thank you so far!

Comment: Given that it works when hard-coded, and not when it is not hard-coded, what can you conclude from that?

Comment: I conclude that I'll post here as soon as I've found a solution for the problem...

Comment: You can conclude that the dynamic input to this function is not what you expect. Find out why by all costs. That's the solution to the problem.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. I use AutoMapper to map EF entities to Data transfer objects and I had the mapping twice in my application. One time with HtmlDecode, one time without. Obviously I opened the page without the HtmlDecode on my local server before the page without and so I saw the correct decoded values. On the remote server (with a little bit of traffic) the other page was opened first and so the wrong mapping was stored. Weird...but with both mappings synced as a quick fix it works as expected.